# サイト移転時にhtaccessで別ディレクトリに301リダイレクトしたい

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess

WordPressを使用し、

```
blog.example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/post-xx
```

のようなディレクトリ構造で運用していたサイトを

```
example.com/blog/post-xx
```

に移転しました。
その場合に旧サイトのpostページを新サイトにリダイレクトするhtaccesの書き方を教えてください。

新旧サイトでpost-のあとに続く数字は共通です。
旧サイトの記事数が膨大なので、全ページ一括で対応できるコードがあれば嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キャプチャが使えそうですね

```
RewriteRule ^blog/AAA/BBB/CCC/post-(.+)$ https://example.com/blog/post-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
私のミスでblog/AAA/BBB/CCC/の部分がそれぞれ上から投稿された年、月、日が入ることを書き忘れていました。
その時はどのように書けば良いか分かりますでしょうか?

Comment: キャプチャを複数利用ですね！